# Image orientation in PopUp

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on Windows Phone 8 application.

I have a image that is being displayed in PopUp. But i have a some criteria like.

`if image width > image height` - `display in landscape mode` else `display in portrait mode`

So how can we acheive this? i have searched for this and found that there is no orienation  property for Popup.

```
double actualHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
double actualWidth = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;

 Grid grid = new Grid();
            grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            grid.Height = actualHeight; //set height
            grid.Width = actualWidth; //set width
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

            Image img = new Image();
            img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            img.Source = bitmapImage;
            img.Tap += OnFullScreenImageTap;

//below i am passing the calculated imageWidth and imageHeight

            if (imageWidth > imageHeight)
            {
                //Landscape
                Debug.WriteLine("Display image in LANDSCAPE");
            }
            else if (imageWidth == imageHeight)
            {
                //Portrait
                Debug.WriteLine("Display image in PORTRAIT");
            }
            else
            {
                //Portrait
                Debug.WriteLine("Display image in PORTRAIT");
            }
            grid.Children.Add(img);

            popUp.Child = grid; //set child content
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(popUp);
            popUp.IsOpen = true;
```

**EDIT**

This is what i have tried as well:

```
RotateTransform  rt = new RotateTransform();
            rt.CenterX = 20;
            rt.CenterY = 20;

            img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            img.Source = bitmapImage;

            if (imageWidth > imageHeight)
            {
                //Landscape

                rt.Angle = 0;
                Debug.WriteLine("Display image in LANDSCAPE");
            }
            else if (imageWidth == imageHeight)
            {
                //Portrait

                rt.Angle = 90;
                Debug.WriteLine("Display image in PORTRAIT");
            }
            else
            {
                //Portrait
                rt.Angle = 90;
                Debug.WriteLine("Display image in PORTRAIT");
            }
            img.RenderTransform = rt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
        double actualHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
        double actualWidth = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        grid.Height = actualHeight; //set height
        grid.Width = actualWidth; //set width
        grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        Image img = new Image();
        img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        img.Source = bitmapImage;
        img.Tap += OnFullScreenImageTap;

        RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform
        rt.CenterX = actualWidth / 2;
        rt.CenterY = actualHeight / 2;

        if (imageWidth > imageHeight)
        {
            //Landscape
            rt.Angle = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine("Display image in LANDSCAPE");
        }
        else if (imageWidth == imageHeight)
        {
            //Portrait
            rt.Angle = 90;
            Debug.WriteLine("Display image in PORTRAIT");
        }
        else
        {
            //Portrait
            rt.Angle = 90;
            Debug.WriteLine("Display image in PORTRAIT");
        }
        grid.Children.Add(img);

        popUp.Child = grid; //set child content
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(popUp);
        popUp.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: I had tried this and for `Landscape mode i have set rt.Angle = 0;` but its still the image shows in portrait

Comment: try setting rt.Angle = 360;

Comment: I guess you need to set the CenterX & CenterY property for Rotate Transform, here this will help you understand how to rotate respect to origin. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.angle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes it works after adding CenterX & CenterY, I have an Image of 40x40 and i set CenterX & CenterY = 20, then set angle = 90 for Portrait & angle = 0 for Landscape, it works.

Comment: Please see my edit, its still displaying only in `portrait mode`

Comment: rt.CenterX = img.Width / 2;
rt.CenterY = img.Height / 2;  try this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52580/discussion-between-goofy-and-vyas-27)

Comment: If you can please join the chat ?